# Graph of Graphs in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a collection of digraphs encoded in the DOT language.  I want to construct a graph-of-graphs such that each node in the super-graph is one of these digraphs.  Is there a way to do this within the GraphViz framework?

I know that `gvpack` will allow me to assemble multiple graphs into one .dot file.  But I don't know if it will allow me to declare edges between those graphs.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is that `gvpack` does not declare edges between the sub-graphs. Indeed, when there are common node names between sub-graphs, `gvpack` renames them to avoid clashes. However, that is fixable.

For example, given three `.dot` files `1.dot`:

```
digraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
    }
```

`2.dot`:

```
digraph {
    D -> E
    E -> F
    }
```

... and `3.dot`:

```
digraph {
    D -> G
    G -> A
    }
```

... running `gvpack -u 1.dot  2.dot 3.dot | dot -Tjpg -ogvp1.jpg` gives the following graph `gvp1.jpg`:

[image]

As you can see, `gvpack` has relabelled the duplicate node names. However, we can easily reverse the re-labelling using `gvpack -u 1.dot  2.dot 3.dot | sed 's/_gv[0-9]\+//g' | dot -Tjpg -ogvsub.jpg`, which produces the following graph `gvsub.jpg`:

[image]

This approach relies on the subgraphs having node names in common, so it might be necessary to insert additional nodes in the sub-graph `.dot` files to achieve this.

(EDIT: The solution above showed the graph with nodes merged but not with the sub-graphs in clusters. The following solution shows the sub-graphs in clusters.)

Given `.dot` files `1.dot` (these are the same as the files above, except I've given each digraph a name):

```
digraph g1 {
    A -> B
    A -> C
    }
```

`2.dot`:

```
digraph g2 {
    D -> E
    E -> F
    }
```

... and `3.dot`:

```
digraph g3 {
    D -> G
    G -> A
    }
```

... along with `hdr.dot`:

```
digraph GMaster {
    compound = true;
    g1 [style=invisible, height = 0, width = 0, label=""];
    g2 [style=invisible, height = 0, width = 0, label=""];
    g3 [style=invisible, height = 0, width = 0, label=""];
    g1 -> g2 [lhead=clusterg2, ltail=clusterg1];
    g1 -> g3 [lhead=clusterg3, ltail=clusterg1]
```

... and `tail.dot`:

```
}
```

... we can run `cat 1.dot 2.dot 3.dot | sed 's/digraph \(\w*\) *{/subgraph cluster\1 { \1/' | cat hdr.dot - tail.dot | dot -Tjpg -oclust1.jpg` to give the file `clust1.jpg`:

[image]

Thus, in the header file, I've added an invisble node to each subgraph, with the same name as the sub-graph, used `compound=true` to allow edges between clusters. I've specified the edges to draw between the clusters and I've set `lhead` and `ltail` for each of the edges between the invisible nodes to ensure that the right cluster is used as the head and tail of each of those edges. I've also added the appropriate invisible node to each subgraph in the process of transforming each subgraph into a cluster using `sed`.

The edges between nodes D, G and A are shown because those nodes are common between the clusters. Also, each of them is only shown in one cluster. If the nodes were unique to the clusters, the only edges that would be shown between clusters would be the edges between the invisible nodes. This can be seen in the following graph, where I've renamed the nodes in `3.dot`:

[image]

There is one remaining flaw that I haven't quite been able to fix. The invisible nodes still take up a little bit of space so the cluster boxes look lopsided because the invisble nodes sit alongside the visible nodes. This also means that the heads of the edges between the clusters point at one side of the cluster box rather than the middle. At present, I can't see what could be done about that, unless we are prepared to look at each subgraph and find a node that is already in that subgraph/cluster to serve as the representative node for that subgraph/cluster (i.e. the one to or from which we draw edges for that cluster). That could be done easily enough by hand for a few subgraphs but it would be tedious if there were many subgraphs.

In contrast, the approach I've used above requires only that we know the name of the cluster and can insert it into the `hdr.dot` file.

I've constructed the `hdr.dot` file by hand for this case but the content of the `hdr.dot` file could be extracted from the other `.dot` files with `sed`, `awk`, `perl` or `python` if there was a need. The script could also insert the edges to link the clusters into `hdr.dot` if information about which clusters should be connected was available somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response Simon.  In my case though I want to treat each of the subgraphs as nodes in the super-graph, not components.  I want to specify that an edge exists between 1->2 and 1->3 and have the subgraphs drawn distinctly, encicrlced as nodes, with the appropriate edges between components.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think joining the subgraphs might be achieved by a similar method to the approach I took in my answer. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how the clusters can be linked by edges.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this would be to allow `gvpack` to perform the renaming, and instead of to attempt to reverse it, to assert the node's label.

Start with

```
digraph g1 {
  A -> B; 
  A -> C;
  A [label="A"];
  B [label="B"];
  C [label="C"];
}
```

and

```
digraph g2 {
  D -> E
  E -> F
  D [label="D"];
  E [label="E"];
  F [label="F"];
}
```

and

```
digraph g3 {
  D -> G
  G -> A
  D [label="D"];
  G [label="G"];
  A [label="A"];
}
```

and you should get the results that you wanted from your original first step

Comment: It'snt a good solution, because the two **D** value not merged

Comment: Yes they are 