# Subgraph has same node, how to make unique

Tags: unique, graphviz, subgraph, nodename

I create dot file by my perl script. Here is subgraphs which contains same node. eg:

```
subgraph{aa->bb->cc;}
subgraph{dd->bb->ee;}
```

I know those subgraph use same namespace, so my result output is a mess.

In each subgraph, I can make them unique, like `bb` and `bb_1` below,

```
subgraph{aa->bb->cc; bb_1->dd;}
```

but it hard to make all node in all subgraphs unique.

Is there some methods to make each subgraph "strict" or use different namespace?

Answer (score 10):

The label presented for a node is only related to the name of the node if it is not overridden by an explicit references.

For example, you can use `"45" [label = "bb"]; "53" [label = "bb"];` to represent two nodes that have the same label.

Then

```
subgraph{aa->"45"->cc;}
subgraph{dd->"53"->ee;}
```

will use the internal id of each node to identify it so that you can then reuse the same label in many locations.

Answer (score 1):

`gvpack` will automatically rename nodes that are in clusters if you use it to put multiple sub-graphs into one graph. See [Graph of Graphs in Graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488216/graph-of-graphs-in-graphviz) for an example.

Comment: thanks. It seems hard to solve it. So I had added line number to each node, although it is hard work for almost 2 days.