# Graphviz: How to include multiple graphs in the same graph?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphviz, pygraphviz

In Jupyter notebook, I am writing code that deals with a graph. It involves a series of transformations on the given graph. I am using graphviz to render the graphs inline. I can only render one graph at a time.

How do I render more than one graph side by side so that I can see successive transformations of the graph?

I know that 'subgraph' can be used to cluster different components of the graph. But I can't use it because it draws connections between all those subgraphs.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't use it because it draws connections between all those subgraphs.

Sounds like the problem is that you have nodes with the same names across different subgraphs.

GraphViz has no per-subgraph namespacing mechanism. Therefore, you will need to somehow make all node names unique, even across subgraphs. You could do this by, for example, prefixing every node name with an unique subgraph ID.

Note that node labels don't need to be the same as node names. For more information, see:
[graphviz: subgraph has same node, how to unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329226/graphviz-subgraph-has-same-node-how-to-unique)