# Merging graphs in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a collection of digraphs encoded in DOT language, and i want to merge them into a single digraph where nodes with the same name in different input graphs are merged together.

For example given the following files:

`1.dot`:

```
digraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
}
```

`2.dot`:

```
digraph {
    D -> E
    E -> F
}
```

`3.dot`:

```
digraph {
    D -> G
    G -> A
}
```

I would like to obtain the following `result.dot`:

```
digraph {
  subgraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
  }
  subgraph {
    D -> E
    E -> F
  }
  subgraph {
    D -> G
    G -> A
  }
}
```

---

I tried to use `gvpack` but it renames duplicate nodes.

```
> gvpack -u 1.dot 2.dot 3.dot
Warning: node D in graph[2] %15 already defined
Some nodes will be renamed.
digraph root {
        node [label="\N"];
        {
                node [label="\N"];
                A -> B;
                A -> C;
        }
        {
                node [label="\N"];
                D -> E;
                E -> F;
        }
        {
                node [label="\N"];
                D_gv1 -> G;
                G -> A_gv1;
        }
}
```

I found [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488216/graph-of-graphs-in-graphviz) that suggest using `sed` to rename the renamed nodes, but that doesn't seem very clean.

Is there a way to merge the graphs the way i would like them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using a [Java library](https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java) to perform the merge, and much more!

With the library i could easily tap into the data structure, change nodes if need be, and add attributes to the graph.

A quick example in Kotlin:

```
// prepare root graph and set direction
val wamap = mutGraph("wamap")
    .setDirected(true)
wamap.graphAttrs().add(RankDir.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)

// add subgraphs from the content of .gv files from disk
Files.walk(Paths.get("D:\\src\\work\\Wamap"), 1)
    .filter { Files.isRegularFile(it) }
    .filter { it.fileName.toString().endsWith(".gv") }
    .map { Parser.read(it.toFile()) }
    .forEach { it.addTo(wamap) }

// normalize node names to lowercase, to ensure nodes with same name are the same node
wamap.graphs()
    .flatMap { it.nodes() }
    .forEach { it.setName(it.name().toString().toLowerCase()) }

// output as file, but also render the image directly with all the possible Graphviz layout engines
File("out/wamap.gv").writeText(wamap.toString())
Engine.values()
    .forEach { engine ->
        Graphviz.fromGraph(wamap).engine(engine).render(Format.PNG).toFile(File("out/wamap-$engine.png"))
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

For exactly the situation you are describing, using the sample files you provide, there is a very simple answer using [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html)  - a standard GNU Linux tool that should be installed by default in most distributions.

Create a file `merge123.m4` with this content:

```
digraph 123 {
define(`digraph',`subgraph')
include(1.dot)
include(2.dot)
include(3.dot)
}
```

and execute it with the command

```
m4 merge123.m4 > 123.dot
```

and the resulting `123.dot` file will be

```
digraph 123 {

subgraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
}

subgraph {
    D -> E
    E -> F
}

subgraph {
    D -> G
    G -> A
}

}
```

If you don't like the empty lines, close each line in the script with `dnl` (the builtin `dnl` stands for “Discard to Next Line”:), for example

```
include(1.dot)dnl
```

`m4` is extremely useful as it adds features to `graphviz` that are really helpful for more involved projects; see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595101/how-can-i-create-named-edge-types-in-graphviz-dot-neato).

EDITED to answer the question in the comment:

If you need to include files and don't know their number and names, you have (at least) two options:

1) If the number of files is rather small and you know all names that they could possibly have, you can `sinclude()` them all:

```
digraph 123 {
define(`digraph',`subgraph')
sinclude(1.dot)
sinclude(2.dot)
sinclude(3.dot)
sinclude(4.dot)
sinclude(5.dot)
}
```

`m4` will only include the files that actually exist, and not complain about the missing ones (the `s` means "silent").

2) If you produce a larger number of`.dot` files with unpredictable names, you will need to do some pre-processing. Create a shell script `include.sh` similar to this one

```
#!/bin/sh
# get *.dot files (or any pattern you like) into one place
ls *.dot > files.txt
# bring them into a format m4 likes
awk '{print "include(" $1 ")" "dnl"}' files.txt > includes.txt
#done
```

`includes.txt` now provides `m4` with the necessary information:

```
include(1.dot)dnl
include(2.dot)dnl
include(3.dot)dnl
```

Now modify your `merge.m4` file, enabling it to make use of the file list provided (I'm adding `dnl` here to avoid lots of empty space in the resulting merged file):

```
### merge dot files
digraph 123 {
define(`digraph',`subgraph')dnl
syscmd(`./include.sh')dnl
include(`includes.txt')dnl
}
```

In order to keep the resulting file separate from the input files, better use a different extension when merging:

```
m4 merge.m4 > merged.gv
```

which now looks like

```
### merge dot files
digraph 123 {
subgraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
}
subgraph {
    D -> E
    E -> F
}
subgraph {
    D -> G
    G -> A
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Is there a way to use `m4` if the number of input files as well as their names is variable?

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just a minor edit of the input files joined, then perl is a natural fit:

```
use strict;
sub main {
  local $/ = undef;
  print "digraph {\n";
  for my $f (@ARGV) {
    open(F, $f) or die $!;
    my $text = <F>;
    close(F);
    $text =~ s/digraph/subgraph/;
    $text =~s/^/  /mg;
    print $text;
  }
  print "}\n";
}

main;
```

Then

```
$ perl merge.pl 1.dot 2.dot 3.dot
digraph {
  subgraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
  }
  subgraph {
    D -> E
    E -> F
  }
  subgraph {
    D -> G
    G -> A
  }
}
```