# GraphViz: How to connect a node within in a subgraph to the sibling node of the subgraph?

Tags: graphviz

I am using subgraphs (clusters) in Graphviz.
Taking help from this link ([GraphViz - How to connect subgraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs)), I am able to connect the subgraphs and nodes with each other.
However, there is one issue:

Suppose we have a digraph G, which contains a subgraph "cluster1" and a node "node1".
Assume "cluster1" contains a single node "node10".
Now, I want to connect "node10" with "node1". I am trying the following code:

```
digraph G {
    compound=true;
    node1;
    subgraph cluster1 {
        node10->node1;    
    }
}
```

This is giving the output where "node1" is present inside "cluster1".
What I want is to have the "node1" outside the "cluster1" and within digraph G.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that link creation takes ownership of *both* ends. Then declaring nodes and link *separately* will work:

```
digraph G {
    compound=true;
    node1;
    subgraph cluster1 {
        node10
    }
    node10->node1
}
```

yields

[image]