# GraphViz: how to connect a node to the containing subgraph

Tags: graphviz, dot, subgraph

I just learned [how to connect nodes and subgraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs) here on Stackoverflow. However, I want to connect a node to the containing subgraph:

```
digraph G {
    compound=true;
    subgraph cluster0 {
        a -> b;
        a -> c;
        c -> {a b c} [lhead=cluster0];
    }
    c -> d;
    d -> {a b c} [lhead=cluster0];
}
```

A quick sketch what I mean:

[image]

I want to connect `d -> {a b c}`, but for clarity reasons, I don't want to draw three different arrows, but just one arrow to the grouping of nodes. One way to do that is only list one arrow, like `d -> a`. That works, but is there a way to "collapse" three arrows into one when the head points to a cluster?

However, `c -> {a b c}` is not possible to point to a cluster, because `c` is part of that cluster. Is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 4):

you will need some scaffolding i.e. invisible node (and maybe edges) e.g.:

```
digraph top {
    compound=true
    node[shape=rectangle]
    subgraph cluster1 {
        a->{b c}
    }
    c->d
    d->b[lhead=cluster1]
    ca[shape=point height=0] // make ca invisible
    a->ca:n[dir=back ltail=cluster1] // by drawing the arrow backward we get more control of the layout, n and s compass make the edge go smooth when enter and exiting ca
    ca:s->c[dir=none] // no arrow on the tail part
}
```

rendered on viz-js.com:

[image]