# how do I add arbitrary, positioned, text/symbols to a graphviz diagram?

Tags: graphviz

I would like to have an "implies" arrow between the two graphs here

```
digraph G {    
    subgraph case {
      x;
      left [shape=diamond];
      right [shape=diamond];
      left -> x;
      right -> x;
    }

    subgraph case_ {
      x_;
      left_ [shape=diamond];
      right_ [shape=diamond];
      left_ -> x_;
      right_ -> x_;
    }
}
```

Trying to [GraphViz - How to connect subgraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036) doesn't work because I'm using the `dot` algorithm. But I don't need anything too fancy since I have a bunch of diagrams like this where there is a "before" and "after" state and I want to put some visual indicator.

Comment: Why not `{ rank = same; x -> x_[ style = dotted, label = "implies" ] }`?

Comment: that's a link between nodes, I want a link between subgraphs

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't exist. You will have to live with a workaround.

Comment: The example you link to should work for dot too, did you forget to rename your subgraph names to start with "cluster" or are you unsatisfied with the resulting layout?