# Clustering subgraphs with singleton/unconnected nodes using neato engine in Graphviz

Tags: visualization, graphviz, dot, subgraph, neato

I'm hoping to generate two subgraphs with the Graphviz `neato` engine.  One subgraph will contain nodes that are connected to each other, the other will contain singleton nodes that aren't connected to any other nodes.  I have adjusted [this](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/cluster.html) example from the Graphviz website below:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape = circle];
    edge [arrowhead = normal, label="", color="#919191"];

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        color=lightgrey;
        label="Singletons";
        a0;
        a1;
        a2;
        a3;
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        color=lightgrey;
        label="Non-singletons";
        b0 -> b1;
        b2 -> b3;
    }
}
```

Which gives the following graph when processed with the `neato` engine where the nodes in each subgraph aren't clustered together.

```
neato -Tpng test.dot > test_neato.png
```

[image]

Processing with the `dot` engine gives alright results but I need to generate networks with a large number of nodes and the `neato` engine is more suitable in this format.

```
dot -Tpng test.dot > test_dot.png
```

[image]

I would like the borders, titles, and clustering (as shown in the example using `dot` above) but using the `neato` engine for positioning the nodes.  Is there a way to do this in Graphviz?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be possible with the `fdp` engine according to discussion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs) thread.

The following command produces a figure that is satisfactory.

```
fdp -Tpng test.dot > test_dot.png
```

[image]