# Multiple graphs inside Graphviz DOT file

Tags: graphviz, dot, flowchart

I have this Graphviz DOT graph:

```
digraph unit_test {
    label="Unit test"
    
    edge [fillcolor="#a6cee3" color="#1f78b4"]

    node[shape="ellipse" style="filled" fillcolor="#1f77b4"]
        start
        end
    node[shape="box" style="filled" fillcolor="#ff7f0e"]
        process
        
    subgraph cluster_process {
        label = "Major logic"
        process
    }
    
    start -> process
    process -> end
    
}
```

The above renders as:

[image: First graph]

I have this second graph:

```
digraph details {
    label = "Process details"
    
    edge [fillcolor="#a6cee3" color="#1f78b4"]
    
    node[shape="ellipse" style="filled" fillcolor="#1f77b4"]
        start
        end
    node[shape="box" style="filled" fillcolor="#ff7f0e"]
        details
    
    subgraph cluster_details {
        label = "Details"
        details
    }
    
    start -> details
    details -> end
}
```

Which renders to:

[image: Second graph]

### Problem

When I put the above two graphs inside the same DOT file named `supporting.dot` and I run `dot -Tpng -o supporting.png supporting.dot` command, terminal prints out some jiberish and the output image file won't contain both graphs, it just contains the first one. Is it possible to use multiple graphs inside a single DOT file? If so, what am I missing?

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: 1) how does your `supporting.dot` look like? Is it just a cut and paste or .... How many digraph statements do you have in your `supporting.dot`? 2) I don't think a dot file can contain multiple digraphs.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is unclear about what is to be accomplished, but maybe the following is a starting point

```
digraph G{
subgraph unit_test {
    label="Unit test"
    
    edge [fillcolor="#a6cee3" color="#1f78b4"]

    node[shape="ellipse" style="filled" fillcolor="#1f77b4"]
        start
        end
    node[shape="box" style="filled" fillcolor="#ff7f0e"]
        process
        
    subgraph cluster_process {
        label = "Major logic"
        process
    }
    
    start -> process
    process -> end
    
}

subgraph details {
    label = "Process details"
    
    edge [fillcolor="#a6cee3" color="#1f78b4"]
    
    node[shape="ellipse" style="filled" fillcolor="#1f77b4"]
        start1 [label="start"]
        end1 [label="end"]
    node[shape="box" style="filled" fillcolor="#ff7f0e"]
        details
    
    subgraph cluster_details {
        label = "Details"
        details
    }
    
    start1 -> details
    details -> end1
}

}
```

Note the naming / labels in the second subgraph.

Answer (score 4):

Dot can't render 2 graphs into a single file, the output you see is probably the content of one of the graphs as a png.

In order to prevent that, you may run your graphs first through [gvpack](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) - something similar to:

```
gvpack -u supporting.dot | dot -Tpng -o supporting.png
```

This combines all graphs in `supporting.dot` into a single graph, which then is rendered with `dot`.

The layout of the graphs can be influenced by some more options of gvpack.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could accept more than one answer. Eventually I went the multiple `subgraph` approach. But your solution/explanation is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 4):

It is legal to have multiple graphs defined in one input file.  You can then produce multiple output files using the **-O** option, like this:

```
dot -Tpng -O multi.gv
```

This will produce **multi.gv.png** and **multi.gv.2.png**

Answer (score 0):

I got a better answer

http://www.bound-t.com/manuals/ref-manual.pdf

**The -dot_dir option and the names of drawing files**

The -dot option creates a single file that contains all drawings from one Bound-T run. If you
then use the dot tool to create a PostScript file, each drawing will go on its own page in the
PostScript file. However, dot can also generate graphical formats that do not have a concept of
"page" and then it may happen that only the first drawing is visible. If you want to use such
non-paged graphical formats it is better to create a directory (folder) to hold the drawing files
and use the Bound-T option -dot_dir instead of the option -dot. The -dot_dir option creates a
separate file for each drawing, named as follows:

• The call-graph of a root subprogram is put in a file called cg_R_nnn.dot, where R is the
link-name of the root subprogram, edited to replace most non-alphanumeric characters
with underscores '_', and nnn is a sequential number to distinguish root subprograms that
have the same name after this editing.

• If the call-graph of some root subrogram is recursive, Bound-T draws the joint call-graph of
all roots and puts it in a file called jcg_all_roots_001.dot.

• The flow-graph of a subprogram is put in a file called fg_S_nnn.dot, where S is the linkname of the subprogram, edited as above, and nnn is a sequential number to distinguish
subprograms that have the same name after this editing and also to distinguish drawings
that show different flow-graphs (execution bounds) for the same subprogram.

The sequential numbers nnn start from 1 and increment by 1 for each drawing file; the same
number sequence is shared by all types of drawings and all subprograms. For example, if we
analyse the root subprogram main?func that calls the two subprograms start$sense and
start$actuate, with the -dot_dir option and -draw options that ask for one flow-graph drawing
of each subprogram, the following drawing files are created:

• cg_main_func_001.dot for the call-graph of main?func

• fg_main_func_002.dot for the flow-graph of main?func

• fg_start_sense_003.dot for the flow-graph of start$sense

• fg_start_actuate_004.dot for the flow-graph of start$actuate.